# Open load detection using SCR

Tags: voltage, power, scr

I have a load I control via back to back SCR during zero crossing circuit. The load is powered via 208Vac and pulls about 15A. I have an EMI filter using safety caps at the output.

I need to detect if the load has a fault gone open. I can only detect if it is faulted open, if I try to apply voltage and the current is not there.

But how can I detect the load fail open during cycles where the load is off?

Comment: "I need to detect if the load has a fault gone open. I can only detect if it is faulted open" can you describe this terminology.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič open load meaning if you have a light bulb but you removed it. Or if you had a resistor and it failed open. The path to the load is open due to failure.

Comment: Just go ahead and throw an AC Current Switch across one of the leads to the load.  Something like this: https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/sensors_-z-_encoders/current_-a-_voltage_sensors_(ac_-a-_dc)/current_switches_-a-_indicators/single_range_ac_current_operated_switches/acsn100-ae-f

Comment: Since the SCR would  be off there wouldn’t be any current. Therefore you can’t determine based on current if the load is just off or the load failed open.

Comment: I still don't get it.